# How do i install new relic on aws elastic beanstalk (windows with .net)?

Tags: newrelic, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I do not seem to to find instructions on how to install new relic on AWS elastic beanstalk (windows with .net). Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Guess it depends on how your configuraiton works. Normally you install the agent (assuming your referring to APM for .NET) into the root directory. FOR ELBS this changes a bit, I found this from a few years back:

Create a top-level directory in your source bundle called .ebextensions and add newrelic.config to it.

Change the values in newrelic.config to match your configuration, where: downloadpathto is the URL to download the PowerShell script and New Relic Agents (e.g. an S3 bucket), platform is the installer appropriate for your system (i.e. x86 or x64), version is the latest version of the New Relic Agent, and newreliclicense_key is your New Relic license key.

Add an application setting to your application's configuration (i.e. web.config) named NewRelic.AppName, and set its value to the name of the application.
Deploy your application to Elastic Beanstalk.

Check out the post here: https://coderwall.com/p/ojqlnq/add-new-relic-to-elastic-beanstalk-for-net

It looks like you need to adjust the NR config file and the EC2 instance information for the agent to spin up within ELBS